# cambiar de base de datos antes de iniciar secion

Tags: php, yii

buenas tardes la verdad espero me ayuden y muchas gracias por cualquier comentario

en el `main` de `yii` se configura la base de datos. pero me gustaría seleccionar a que Base de datos quiero entrar sin necesidad de ir al `main` de `yii` como podría lograrlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es agregar más bases de datos en el main de yii,
después agregar una lógica en caso de que uses el login en tu página que al iniciar secion por un parámetro determine que base de datos utilizar,

se me ocurre tener una única base de datos para validar a los usuarios y en ella puedes determinar qué conexion utilizar,pero en el main de yii 1.x es requisito agregar las conexiones.

```
   'db1' => array( //db de Calidad
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    'db2' => array( //db de Desarrollo
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.